# Plot a list contains many lists with R

Tags: r, list, plot

I have a list like this, the number above $`1081786081` is the user id, I want to plot the day_count according to time.

It's easy to do that if it's a data frame

```
plot(list4$day_count)
```

But I don't know how to do it for each list.Should I use lapply?

```
$`1081786081`
         time day_count
1  2016-01-13         2
2  2016-01-20         2
3  2016-02-06         2
4  2016-02-23         2
5  2016-03-14         2
6  2016-03-24         2
7  2016-04-06         2
8  2016-04-11         2
9  2016-05-04         2
10 2016-06-06         2
11 2016-06-26         2
12 2016-07-01         2

$`1087949661`
         time day_count
1  2016-01-02         4
2  2016-01-11         2
3  2016-01-20         2
4  2016-01-21         6
5  2016-01-22         2
6  2016-01-27         4
7  2016-01-30         4
8  2016-02-02         2
9  2016-02-05         2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to plot the `list` of `data.frame`s in a single `pdf` with separate pages for each plot, after setting the output `.pdf`, we loop through the 'list4', and `plot`.

```
pdf("yourplot.pdf")
invisible(lapply(list4, function(x) with(x, plot(time, day_count))))
dev.off()
```

We can also create some identifier for each `plot` by looping through the `names` of the `list` elements

```
pdf("yourplot.pdf")
invisible(lapply(names(list4), function(nm) with(list4[[nm]],
             plot(time, day_count, main = paste("plot of", nm)))))
dev.off()
```

---

If we need a single plot with lines, we can `rbind` the `list` elements and then do the `plot`ting.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
bind_rows(list4, .id = "grp") %>%
       ggplot(., aes(x=time, y = day_count, colour = grp)) + 
       geom_line() +
       geom_point()
```

#### data

```
list4 <- structure(list(`1081786081` = structure(list(time = structure(c(16813, 
16820, 16837, 16854, 16874, 16884, 16897, 16902, 16925, 16958, 
16978, 16983), class = "Date"), day_count = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("time", "day_count"
), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"10", "11", "12"), class = "data.frame"), `1087949661` = structure(list(
time = structure(c(16802, 16811, 16820, 16821, 16822, 16827, 
16830, 16833, 16836), class = "Date"), day_count = c(4L, 
2L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("time", "day_count"
), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), 
class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("1081786081", 
"1087949661"))
```

Comment: what if I plot lines and I want all the lines to be on the same graph?

Comment: @Lucia You can use the `type` i.e. `invisible(lapply(names(list4), function(nm) with(list4[[nm]],plot(time, day_count, type = "b", main = paste("plot of", nm)))))` or `type = "l"`

Comment: @Lucia Regarding all the lines on the same graph is not clear.  Do you want to have a single dataset with another grouping variable.

Comment: Actually this giant list has a thousand sublists, I'm trying to plot each sublist on the same graph and if I set the ylim to be large enough, there should be a rough pattern of the trend.

Comment: @Lucia Updated with a `ggplot/dplyr` option